# Derived functors of exact (contravariant) functor are trivial

Tags: solution-verification, derived-functors

I'm new to projective resolutions, derived functors, etc, so I'd like a proof check of my proof that the derived functors of an exact contravariant functor are trivial.

Suppose that $F$ is an exact contravariant functor and let $M$ be a module over some commutative ring $R$. Take a projective resolution of $M$,
$$ \cdots \to P_2 \to P_1 \to P_0 \twoheadrightarrow  M. $$
Remove the term $M$, and apply $F$ to obtain the chain complex
\begin{equation}\label{eq}
F(P_0) \to F(P_1) \to F(P_2) \to \cdots.
\end{equation}
This sequence is exact, since $F$ is. It therefore has trivial homology, which shows that all right derived functors of $F$ are $0$.

To show that all left derived functors of $F$ are $0$, we instead take an injective resolution of $M$ and follow the same procedure. EDIT: I included this, just for the sake of completeness:

Let 
$$ M \hookrightarrow I_0 \to I_1 \to I_2 \to \cdots  $$
be an injective resolution of $M$. Again, remove the term $M$ and apply $F$ to obtain
$$ \dots \to F(I_2) \to F(I_1) \to F(I_0). $$
Just as before, this complex has trivial homology.

Any corrections or tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems to be fine to me.

Comment: It is all right. Very good.

Comment: @NDewolf I just realized, isn't this wrong? For example, when proving that $F$'s left derived functors are trivial, since $F$ is contravariant, we are supposed to choose an injective resolution in R-Mod$^{op}$, which corresponds to a projective resolution in R-Mod.

Comment: But you already did this. For covariant functors one generally starts with injective resolutions for right derived functors and projective resolutions for left derived functors. However since the direction is reversed for contravariant functors one should interchaznge the types of resolutions. As you did.

Comment: @NDewolf Oh, what a brain fart... Anyhow, thanks again!